# Command Timeout parameter in postgresql connection string is not working properly in npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql, command-timeout

I am trying to configure command timeout within the connection string as follows:

```
`"ConnectionStrings": {
    "EFCoreConnection" : "Host=localhost;Database=EFCoreCommandTimeoutTest;Username=postgres;Password=postgress;Command Timeout=300"
  }`
```

but when I debug and evaluate `dbContext.Database.GetCommandTimeout()` method call inside my api handler I got `null` only. I am aware that I could configure command timeout when I configure npgsql as follows:

```
`builder.Services
    // .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
       options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EFCoreConnection"),
            config => config.CommandTimeout(300));
    });
`
```

but that's not what I need, I am trying to configure that inside connection string because we use Azure App Configuration and we store connection string in there and we don't want to introduce another secret in Azure App Configuration for only command timeout. We are going to store the command timeout along with connection string and that's my goal here.

I tried to use the connection string example from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/setting-command-timeout/) but still got `null` when I evaluate `dbContext.Database.GetCommandTimeout()` method call. I was sure that my connection string is correct according to [this documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive).

Comment: If you want to let this timeout value to be set by connection string, I suggest you could consider setting it by using another appsetting.json value, you could create a new value called sqltimeout and get it inside the program.cs.  This should match your requirement.

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang yeah I could but I need to setup command timeout only inside connection string because I do not want to introduce another configuration just for command timeout as there is a way for setting it up in connection string but as I stated on the question this approach didn't work well but I want to make it work and that's why I asked for help here